# "Slow Storage Writes on Drive T" warning from sp_Blitz

Tags: sql-server, storage, sp-blitz

We migrated our platform to new SQL Server 2016 instances a couple of nights ago. Immediately following the migration, we ran sp_Blitz again, but noticed the following entry, which relates to the dedicated volume holding tempdb (all eight data files and the single log file reside on the same dedicated volume). All of the database volumes are using SSDs so this is somewhat surprising:

> Slow Storage Writes on Drive T Writes are averaging longer than 100ms
>   for at least one database on this drive.  For specific database file
>   speeds, run the query from the information link.

No link was provided, but delving into the code, we found that sp_Blitz uses dm_io_virtual_file_stats to assess the following logic:

o_stall_write_ms / ( 1.0 + num_of_writes ) ) > 100 AND num_of_writes > 100000

Using this logic, the function points to all eight of our tempdb data files, with write speeds of between 164-198ms, which suggests we have a serious issue.

[image: Results from dm_io_virtual_file_stats]

To prove the issue to management, we have since run Performance Monitor traces to review the "Avg. Disk sec/Write" counter for all volumes attached to the server, but the T volume did not appear to be any slower than the other volumes during the working-hours time frame we sampled.

We have since run CrystalDiskMark against the OS, Data, Log and tempdb volumes on the secondary (log shipped) server, which uses the same SAN storage as the server which raised the sp_Blitz warning. All storage volumes show very similar figures to the below.

[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

- Are the CrystalDiskMark speeds expected figures for SSDs, and are they consistent with the warnings in sp_Blitz?
- Are we using the wrong PerfMon counter to prove this? If so, what counter should we use?
- Is the above function showing us live speeds, or just the worst speed it ever encountered (i.e. should we ignore this warning, unless it is still there after the next server restart)?
- Could anyone please provide further insight/advice?

Comment: Can you run Crystal Disk Mark and share the results? https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/

Comment: Also, search your error log for "15 seconds" and see if you have any warnings.

Comment: A SQL Server error log string search of "15 seconds" just came up some database backup and CHECKDB entries. Looking into using Crystal Disk Mark, but this is our production server and I see there is an overhead. Would you recommend we run this test overnight/off-peak?

Comment: If you have to ask...

Comment: What PerfMon counters we could use in the meantime, whilst we look at scheduling downtime? Are these unlikely to highlight the issue?

Comment: I've never had much luck with them for this.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - CrystalDiskMark figures for secondary server above (still looking to run this on primary server, but have been assured they point to same SAN storage). Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Serious question: Is your SAN a used SD card from 2005?

Comment: Do you know how many paths you have to the SAN? I've often found the lack of connections can be an issue.

Comment: 1) The fact that you see *any* 15 second errors means something is wrong/misconfigured/overworked for the IO subsystem. 2) Latency and Bandwidth are two completely separate things. 3) Those bandwidth values are *horrible* if this is all SSD. 4) Perfmon aggregates like Avg Disk Sec/Transfer are aggregates. Thus, if you are seeing wait times of over 15 seconds and averages that are low, the slow ones are being hidden by the average. 5) you're more than likely going to need to run a storport trace and investigate specifically around the 15 second errors.

Comment: Is this a 3par with dedupe enabled?